# Xcode Firebase Missing Authorization String In "aps-environment"

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor, xcode14

I am trying to setup my push notifications for ios on my app with ionic angular and capacitor. When I deploy to iPhone the console log is displaying this ...  **To Native ->  PushNotifications register 3039262**

**⚡️  TO JS undefined**

**2023-08-08 17:09:04.685066-0600 App[3699:742039] 10.13.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: no se encontró ninguna cadena de autorización “aps-environment” para la app**

[image]

So, no push notifications working for my app.

This is my AppDelegate

I have all my configurations on place (apparently) as you may see on the image below. And on my AppDelegate I added the FirebaseCore and initialized it as it shows on the tutorial. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push-notifications

As well as I addsed this strings on my info.plist

```
 <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
      <string>fetch</string>
      <string>processing</string>
      <string>remote-notification</string>
  </array>
```

So, I don't know where I missed something. I have reviwed all of the other cases exposed in here on other questions similar to this one but the solution was to add push notifications from Capabilities, but I did and have it on my Target configurations already. Please help me.

[image]